# Makefile: nested dependency

Tags: makefile

I have a lecture consisting of interconnected tex files. `lecture.tex` uses pictures in pdf format in `/pictures/output` folder. They are being produced from `tex` files in `/pictures` folder.

```
lecture.tex
makefile
/pictures
   /output
     01_picture.pdf
     02_picture.pdf
   01_picture.tex
   02_picture.tex
   makefile
```

I created a makefile for pictures (it works fine):

```
COMMAND = pdflatex
FLAGS = #-quiet
FILES = $(wildcard ./[0-9]*.tex)
.PHONY = all create_dir
OUTPUTDIR="output"

all: create_dir $(patsubst ./%.tex,./output/%.pdf,$(FILES))

create_dir:
    @if [ ! -d $(OUTPUTDIR) ]; then \
        mkdir $(OUTPUTDIR); \
    fi

./output/%.pdf: %.tex
    $(COMMAND) $(FLAGS) $*.tex
    mv ./$*.pdf ./output
    rm ./$*.aux ./$*.log
```

Now when compiling lecture, we need to do:

```
if(any pictures tex files were modified)
    recompile picture pdf
    recompile lecture.tex
```

I tried to do it with this main makefile:

```
COMMAND = pdflatex
FLAGS = #-quiet
.PHONY = pictures

all: lecture.pdf

lecture.pdf: pictures lecture.tex
    $(COMMAND) $(FLAGS) lecture.tex

pictures:
    make -C pictures
```

But it doesn't work. Or maybe, I need just 1 makefile for everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use one makefile, and express the dependencies correctly:

```
pictures := pictures
output   := $(pictures)/output

PDFLATEX      := pdflatex
PDFLATEXFLAGS := #-quiet
COMPILE.pdf   := $(PDFLATEX) $(PDFLATEXFLAGS)

pictures_tex := $(wildcard $(pictures)/[0-9]*.tex)
pictures_pdf := $(pictures_tex:$(pictures)/%.tex=$(output)/%.pdf)

lecture.pdf: lecture.tex $(pictures_pdf)
    $(COMPILE.pdf) $<

$(output)/%.pdf: $(pictures)/%.tex | $(output)
    $(COMPILE.pdf) -output-directory $| $<
    $(RM) $(output)/$*.aux $(output)/$*.log

$(output): ; mkdir -p $@
```

Comment: Is it possible to tell make that it must use files in pictures folder? I don't see it in your makefile.

Comment: There are some pictures, that use internal files located in `pictures` folder. I tried `cd pictures && $(COMPILE.pdf) -output-directory $(OUTPUT) $<`, but it gives an error: `pictures/01_picture.tex not found` as we are inside pictures folder. Or maybe, accept your answer and write this as a separate question?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with tex, there should be an option to change the working and/or include directory though.